# using awk on a string

Tags: linux, bash, awk

can I use awk to extract the first column or any column  on a string?
Actually i am using a file and reading it to a variable I want to use AWK on that variable and  do my job.

How is it possible? Any suggestions.

Comment: What are your column separators?

Comment: In many cases, it's better to let AWK do the file processing (or at least use a shell `while read` loop) rather than reading a file into a variable.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Print first column*:

```
<some output producing command> | awk '{print $1}'
```

Print second column:

```
<some output producing command> | awk '{print $2}'
```

etc.

Where `<some output producing command>` is like `cat filename.txt` or `echo $VAR`, etc.

e.g. `ls -l | awk '{print $9}'` extracts the ninth column, which is like an ... awkward way of `ls -1`

*Columns are defined by the separating whitespace.

---

EDIT: If your text is already in a variable, something like:

```
VAR2=$(echo $VAR | awk '{print $9}')
```

would work, provided you change 9 to the desired column.

Comment: with bash you can use a "here-string": `VAR2=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "$VAR1")`